# ViewPager index not correct when sending to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm sending the position of the ViewPager to a fragment State_Pager which then displays them on the screen.  However, the problem I'm having is when I swipe through the list.  There are three pages, and on launch the screen will display 0, 1, 2.  But swiping back from 2 results in 2, 1, 2 instead of 2, 1, 0.  It is worth noting that the Title is always correct.

I've tried replacing position with ViewPager.getCurrentItem() and packaging that into the fragment, but to the same avail.

```
public static class VehicleModePageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {

    public VehicleModePageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return State_Pager.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumModes;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (mPageType) {
            case 0:
            case 3:
                return "Title " + position;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (mPageType) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return "Title " + position;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The title for the ViewPager works, but its when I send that variable to the Fragment State_Pager, the State_Pager fragment will display the correct position when scrolling to the right, but will not display the correct position when scrolling to the the left.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me. I created a list of fragments and a list of titles, in this way i have the control of each view by position and i don´t have a problem to scrolling to the left.

```
public static class VehicleModePageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public VehicleModePageAdapter(FragmentManager fm){ super(fm); }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

You can fill the PagerAdapter like this.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    VehicleModePageAdapter adapter = new VehicleModePageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentVehicle(), "Category 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentVehicle(), "Category 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentVehicle(), "Category 3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so I found out was the problem was.  When I was creating the fragment State_Pager, I was un-bundling the position in the OnCreate menu when I should have been un-bundling in the OnCreateView.